# Show column value twice in MySql Select

Tags: mysql, select

If I have a MySql table with values

```
col1
=====
1
1
1
5
5
5
5
7
7
```

I want to get all distinct values of col1 (i.e. 1,5,) and get output with one SELECT statement as follows:

```
1~1
5~5
7~7
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what if more than two identical values exist? what will be your output then?

Comment: ＠1000111:I rephrase my question to show what I really want? Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Both answers will give you what you want, where is the confusion?  Did you even try to run the fiddles?

Comment: I want check both answers but I can only check one, so I check the 1st in the listing order of this page. But I raise the agree-counter (vote counter, I guess) of both of your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the query:

Use separator `~` in `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

**Query #1 use case scenario:** If you want to separate the `col1` values by tide (`~`) only if the corresponding value has identical values across the table.

**Query #1**:

```
SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(col1 SEPARATOR '~') output
FROM scotttable
GROUP BY col1;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/355d3f/1/0)

**Note:** It will work for any number of identical values.

---

**Query #2 use case scenario:** Only if you want the `distinct col1` values no matter if they have corresponding identical value across the table exists or not.

**Query #2**:

```
SELECT 
 CONCAT(col1,'~',col1) output
FROM scotttable
GROUP BY col1;
```

[**FIDDLE OF THIS QUERY**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/355d3f/5/0)

Comment: Yes! I want them to be identical. And what if the value repleat more than twice in the table? Say, 3 of '1', 4 of '5'.

Comment: For this sample input `1 1 1 4 5` you will get output like `1~1~1
4
5` through the first query.

Comment: Please check this [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37714/1/0). Sample input is `1 1 1 5 5 7 7` @ScottChu

Comment: I rephrase my question to show more clear what I want. For values 1,1,1, I still want output as 1~1, rather than 1~1~1. And thanks for reminding me in the comment of my question. Sorry for vague question before.

Comment: The you should go for **query #2** in my answer. @ScottChu

Comment: Thanks, Query #2 is exactly what I want.

Comment: I want check both answers (I mean yours and Tim's) but it only allows one. Don't know why?

Comment: There can be at most one `Checked or Accepted answer`. Stackoverflow rule @ScottChu

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using a subquery:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.value, '~', t.value)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col1 AS value
    FROM yourTable
) t
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Hi Tim! For values which don't have any similar value across the table it might give wrong output. Consider this set of input values `1

5

7
`

Comment: @1000111 `I want to get distinct value of col1` ... what part of the question is not clear, or what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry. May be I am wrong. The sample input and output gave me an implicit feeling : rows in output should consist the identical values separated by tide (`~`).

Comment: @Tim: I mean: Say if there are 1,1,1,5,5,5,5,7,7, I want get the distinct values first, i.e. 1,5, and 7, then output as 1~1, 5~5, 7~7. I rephrase my question and hope it's clear now.

Comment: @ScottChu I'm not sure what you want, but both of the answers will give you the output you requested in your question.

Comment: @Tim:Sorry for posting my comment in wrong place. The comment should be under 1000111's answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I want.Thanks!

Comment: I want check both answers (I mean yours and 1000111's) but it only allows one. Don't know why?